Can not load the safetensors huggingface model in DJL in Java
I tried a lot, but I want to read embeddings from the jina embeddings
this is my java code:
public static float[] getTextEmbedding(String text) throws ModelNotFoundException, MalformedModelException, IOException, TranslateException {
        Criteria<String, float[]> criteria = Criteria.builder()
                .setTypes(String.class, float[].class)
                .optEngine("PyTorch")
                .optModelPath(Paths.get("/jina-embeddings-v2-base-de"))
                .optTranslator(
                    TextEmbeddingTranslator
                        .builder(HuggingFaceTokenizer.newInstance(Paths.get("/jina-embeddings-v2-base-de")))
                        .build()
                )
                .optProgress(new ProgressBar())
                .optOption("trust_remote_code", "true")
                .build();

        try (Predictor<String, float[]> predictor = ModelZoo.loadModel(criteria).newPredictor()) {
            return predictor.predict(text);
        }
    }

but I keept getting this error:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: jina-embeddings-v2-base-de.pt file not found in: /jina-embeddings-v2-base-de


What files are there in your /jina-embeddings-v2-base-de folder? Can you try to convert the model using djl-convert

Converting would work, but since I want to experiment with different models, I hoped I could somehow get it to work like this. The base folder is basically the repo, which is linked in my post.

djl-convert can convert local model into DJL format as well:
djl-convert -m /jina-embeddings-v2-base-de

Then you can point to model/jina-embeddings-v2-base-de folder in Java code.
You will find the following files in the folder:

jina-embeddings-v2-base-de.pt
config.json
serving.properties
tokenizer_config.json
tokenizer.json

